# Beamer: Frame Number in Header in Frankfurt Theme

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, themes

I use the theme `frankfurt` in my beamer presentations. At the same time, I use `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]`in order to get frame numbers.

In `Frankfurt`the header is divided in two parts: on the top you see the sections, beneath you see the frame title. The frame number is displayed on the bottom right.

Recently, I saw a PowerPoint presentation where next to the headlines in the header the frame number was displayed.

My **Question**: Is it possible to include the frame number into the headline part of the header of the `frankfurt`theme on the right side? And how to do so?

WE

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt} 
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif} 
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=light-gray}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.80}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %dt. Silbentrennung
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} %Richtiges Sprach-Funktionieren am Mac
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\begin{document}
\section{asdf}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hund}
\end{frame}

\section{bsdf}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Katze}
\end{frame}

\section{csdf}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Maus}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code shortens navigation line and includes page number on left side.
Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt} 
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif} 
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=light-gray}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.80}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %dt. Silbentrennung
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} %Richtiges Sprach-Funktionieren am Mac
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{my smoothbars theme}
{%
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \vskip-9.75ex%
  \else%
    \vskip-7ex%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
    \insertnavigation{.9\paperwidth}\hfill\insertpagenumber\hspace{.5em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{asdf}
\subsection{abcd}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hund}
\end{frame}

\section{bsdf}
\subsection{abcd}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Katze}
\end{frame}

\section{csdf}
\subsection{abcd}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Maus}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is what I am looking for. However, is it possible to do a minor adjustment: Is it possible to include a frame number in the style of 2/33 (instead of 2) according to the `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]`.

Comment: Yes, replace `\insertframenumber` with `\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber`.

Comment: I replaced `\insertpagenumber` with  `\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber`. And now it works. However, I have one more question: Is it possible to change the frame numbers to the same color as the headlines in the header.